# How to block websites using python program written with discord .py in the other user's computer who are in the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote a python program to block websites .I created a bot in discord which includes this program and I added this bot in a server so that all users in the server can block websites in their respective devices. But when the user tries to block websites using the discord bot, it does not block in their computer but instead blocks them in my system. How can I fix this? Please help!

**bot.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

async def block(ctx,message):
                global new
                found=1
                new=message.split(",")
                new2=[]
                for i in new:
                    i="www"+"."+i
                    new2+=[i]
                new.extend(new2)
                from blocksites import blocksite
                blocksite(new,found)
                await ctx.send(file=discord.File("blocksites.py"))
```

**blocksites.py**

```
hosts_path="C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
def blocksite(websites,found):
        while True:
            if found==1:
                print("block sites",websites)
                with open(hosts_path,"r+") as hostsfile:
                    hosts_content=hostsfile.read()
                    for site in websites:
                        if site not in hosts_content:
                            hostsfile.write(redirect + " " + site + "\n")
                break
            elif found==0:
                print("unblock sites")
                with open(hosts_path,"r+") as hostsfile:
                    lines=hostsfile.readlines()
                    hostsfile.seek(0)
                    for line in lines:
                        if not any(site in line for site in websites):
                            hostsfile.write(line)
                    hostsfile.truncate()
                    break
```

Comment: If you're running this from your computer, then it will most definitely block the sites on your computer. They may be using the commands on Discord from their own computers, but the program is not _running_ on their computer. Similarly, if this is hosted on a server, this would only block websites for the server (which does pretty much nothing). **TL;DR** You can't block a website on another person's computer unless you're actually _on_ that person's computer.

Answer (score -2):

change your code to this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

async def block(ctx,message):
                global new
                found=1
                new=message.split(",")
                new2=[]
                for i in new:
                    i="www"+"."+i
                    new2+=[i]
                new.extend(new2)
                from blocksites import blocksite
                blocksite(new,found)
                await ctx.send(file=discord.File("blocksites.py"))
```

blocksites.py

```py
hosts_path="C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
def blocksite(websites,found):
        while True:
            if found==1:
                print("block sites",websites)
                with open(hosts_path,"r+") as hostsfile:
                    hosts_content=hostsfile.read()
                    for site in websites:
                        if site not in hosts_content:
                            hostsfile.write(redirect + " " + site + "\n")
                break
            elif found==0:
                print("unblock sites")
                with open(hosts_path,"r+") as hostsfile:
                    lines=hostsfile.readlines()
                    hostsfile.seek(0)
                    for line in lines:
                        if not any(site in line for site in websites):
                            hostsfile.write(line)
                    hostsfile.truncate()
                    break
```

Comment: What have you exactly changed here? Also please add a useful explanation instead of a vague "change your code to this"